# Method Not Allowed (POST)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to allow for the user to press the submit and for that to create another comment post but I receive "Method Not Allowed (POST): " when clicking post

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # post = Post.objects.filter(id = self.kwargs['pk'])
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-id')
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            content = self.request.POST.get('content')
            comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post, user=self.request.user, content=content)
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    context['is_liked'] = is_liked
    context['total_likes'] = post.total_likes()
    context['comments'] = comments
    context['comment_form'] = comment_form
    return context
```

and for the template:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ comment_form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
```

Comment: You need to show the rest of the view class, not just the get_context_data method. Does it define a `post` method, or inherit from a class that does?

Comment: But note that you certainly shouldn't be doing things like processing forms in the get_context_data method. That's for, well, getting context data.

Comment: I've changed my question to include the whole class. How would you process the form?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: You should use a form view - in this case, a CreateView. Your code wouldn't work at all, you can only return *context* from that method, not a redirect for example.

Comment: The problem with a create view is that I was display a post with the DetailView  but i want to display and create comments

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L103), you can't use `POST` method in `DetailView`. It only support `get`.

If you want to use `POST`, you should use formview or inherit formmixin.